# Convert Flash AS3 Games into HTML5 Games

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I want to convert Flash Game (AS3) to Html5 Game. I have all assets like .fla file and all .as files. But I am unable to find any tool or way to convert that into html5 game.

I used Flash CS6 using toolkit for CreateJS but it only converts animation in html5. I also tried to use Google's Swiffy extension in Flash CS6, but it was also not working. I think Swiffy is now discontinued by Google.

**Question**:
So is there any way to convert Flash/AS3 sources with interactivity into html5?

**[EDIT]**
I also tried to use google swiffy extension in Adobe Flash Pro CS6 but it was also not working. I think google swiffy is now discontinued.

Comment: http://www.sothink.com/tutorials/how-to-convert-flash-to-html.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you have any actionscript in your game (which I assume a game would) it won't convert property with the common swf conversion tools out there. Regardless, interpreted script games (such as the JVM in this case) are disgusting and just further the PC requirements of your users. Your only two options are to stick with Actionscript or to build it from scratch. You can find [as3 to javascript converters](https://as3js.org) for your class files but there's other things such a lib dependencies and other factors that you'd have to take account for.

If all of your logic is in your frames:

1. Please dont do that again.
2. Convert your frame code to Class files
3. Use the converter